# wordpress integration with codeigniter base functions conflict

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

I have developed the CRM based web application what i need to do is to integrate the wordpres with my CI first i have the problem when i include the main WP file

```
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
```

in my one of the CI view file the error i was getting that function site_url() conflicts this function is the base function of both WP and CI ,although i found a solution to include the WP file in the main index.php file of CI but there is uncertainity too that after this the session library of CI stops working is.

How to show the posts of WP in the footer of my CRM?

Answer (score 0):

When using include or require in my CodeIgniter views I make sure the files I am linking to are outside of the CodeIgniter application folder as I had trouble using files there because of some permission problems.  My solution was to just keep a folder in my web directory.  You also cannot use base_url or site_url CodeIgniter functions here since you want to get the server path not the web address of the file.  So you can use the php variable `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` which will return the root of your web directory.
It might look something like this:

```
 require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'wp-blog-header.php');
```

Which would work if wp-blog-header.php was in your web root directory.

Comment: I have already tried this by putting WP in root directory it resolves the conflict issue but my session library of CI isn't working after that

Comment: Another solution might be to place the wp-blog-header file in your views folder and load it in your controller with your view.  Just rememberyou will have to modify the src of any outside files it is dependent on.